# Printing with column padding when string features variables

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I've managed to print left-aligned padded columns when the output is static like this:

```
int col = 40;
printf("%-*s", col, "padded column");
printf("after the column\n");
```

I'm trying to do the same when the string is not static but formatted with a variable, ie:

```
int col = 40;
int var1 = 200;
printf("???", col, var1, " padded column");
printf("after the column\n");
```

Where the expected output would be, for example:

```
200 padded column                  after padded column
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why is `%d` not good enough?

Comment: @user694733 Well my problem is that this `printf("%-*s", col, "%d padded column", var1);` is of course not valid, and this `printf("%d%-*s", var1, col, " padded column");` doesn't generate a *total width* of `col`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate text in 2 parts:

```
char paddedColText[100];
snprintf(paddedColText, sizeof paddedColText, "%d padded column", var1);
printf("%-*s", col, paddedColText);
```

or, alternative:

```
col -= printf("%d", var1); // Returns string length
printf("%-*s", col, " padded column");
```

But keep in mind that `printf` *can* return negative error code, so checking the return value before using is a good idea.